# Integrating this (rather messy) integral and determining the limiting behaviour

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

From a preceding question I have worked on, an integral to evaluate:

> $$\frac{2i\sqrt{a}}{(a^2+1)}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty k\cdot\exp\bigg[i\bigg(k-\frac{k^{2}ht}{2m}\bigg)\bigg]~dk$$

I need to determine the limiting cases for large **a** and small **a**.

However, the integrand looks rather messy. Would I be required  to resort to generalized functions, or is this a case of brute force integration by parts ?

Comment: The integral is not convergent as written.

Comment: The integral does not depend on $a$. Is this right?

Comment: The integral does not depends on a. I think what the question requires is that I determine first the integrand. Then determine the limiting cases as a whole@JendrikStelzner

Comment: If you replace $exp[ik]$ by $exp[ibk]$ then you can rewrite the integral as a $b$-derivative of the Fourier transform of $exp[i{k^2}ht/(2m)]$. This may exist as a distribution, I don't know.

Comment: Assuming that the integral exists, say with value $I$ then the limits are determined by the $a$-dependent prefactor which vanishes for both $a=0$ and $a→∞$.